# Is MLP:FiM canon to any past MLP show?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

It is a know fact since the first episode of the My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic show that for some reason the sun and moon in Equestria do not move on their own, requiring ponies to do the work themselves. In the current era the task is performed by Celestia and Luna but before that multiple unicorns permanently lost their magic due to the big strain the spell put on regular ponies (this is referenced in the Journal side book).

Later episodes such as "Winter Wrap Up" also open the door to other possible implications, like seasons being stuck in a permanent state. It is unclear if ponies are the sole responsible for the existence of winter and summer, but it seem a quite probable explanation.

Anyway, even not considering seasons it is clear that something is going up with Equestria. Day and night are stuck in a frozen state for no apparent reason given.

Over the course of the nine season of the show no explanation is ever given for this phenomena so I was wondering. Would any event from previous generations of the My Little Pony show justify the existence of a world frozen in time or is all of this just something that came up to justify Celestia and Luna roles and their original conflicts?

Comment: Institutionalized Copernicism shaping how biased heliocentrically-entitled elitists try to understand Ptolemaic/geocentric universes?